# Pass a custom function as template parameter within 1 statement

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, readability

I successfully passed a function as parameter.

```
// this is in a scope of a normal function
class DummyClass{
    public: static int dummyFunction(G& goo){
        return goo.doSomething (); //non-static function
        //Edit 3: it calculates hash value
    }
};
AMap<G,int,DummyClass::dummyFunction>map;
//... do some other thing
```

Those Dummy reduce readability of the code.

Can I call it in a more concise way?

```
AMap<G,int,
    [](G&goo)->int{ return goo.doSomething (); }
>map;
```

I tried, but the compiler said

```
expected compile-time constant expression
```

It looks like compiler thought that the lambda function is not compile-time constant, but I am sure its behavior is.

I have read [How to use a lambda expression as a template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810519/how-to-use-a-lambda-expression-as-a-template-parameter) , but no solution can offer 1-statement way.

I would be ideal if I can call it like

```
AMap<G,int, G::doSomething >map; //note that G::doSomething is non-static
```

**Edit**

This is how I declared AMap

```
template<class K,class T,int (* K_uniqueHash)(K&) >AMap {//<--- can be changed
    private: int getIndex(K& k){
        return K_uniqueHash(k);  //<--- can be changed
    }
    //.. other function
}
```

Your answer can also change codes of the above class.

**Edit 2:** Any modification toward AMap doesn't count as additional lines, because it is a library.

**Edit 3:** Sorry, my template may be misleading.

A map only use 1 function for hashing.

```
template<class K,class T,int (* K_uniqueHash)(K&) >AMap
          ^key    ^value      ^ hashing function
```

Therefore, I don't expect to assign 1 function per 1 key.

In other words, loosely speaking ....

```
AMap<K,T,k_hasher> aMap;  
K k1,k2;  T t1,t2;
aMap[ k1 ] = t1;  aMap[ k2 ] =t2;
// Then, these statements below will be called internally.
k1.k_hasher(); 
k2.k_hasher();  //every k call same function "k_hasher"
```

Comment: Did you already try [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)?

Comment: A canonical way is to pass a type of a function object as a type-template argument, store it in a class, and initialize it in a class constructor

Comment: I guess that you mean : pass function as an argument - with in () - of AMap's constructor", right?    It seems to require another line of code.

Comment: @javaLover, unless you are code golfing - that seems like an arbitrary requirement!?!

Comment: I really want to increase readability, because it will be in my core c++ library.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `std::function` instead:

```
AMap<G,int, std::function<int(G&)>> m;
```

Edit:

You could change your `AMap` class as follows:

```
template<typename K, typename T, typename F>
class AMap {
  int getIndex(K& k) { return K_uniqueHash(k); }
  // ...
};
```

Suppossed that you have a `class Foo` with a member function `bar`:

```
struct Foo {
  int bar(G&); 
};
```

You could pass member functions as well as lambdas etc as:

```
AMap<G,int, std::function<int(G&)>> m;
auto f = [](G &i)->int { return 42; };
m[0] = f; // if your class works like a map
Foo foo;
m[2] = std::bind(&Foo::bar, &foo, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: Thank, but how can I tell that map to use a certain function like "G::doSomething"?

Comment: @javaLover member functions are not ordinary functions per se. They must be bind with an object of their respective class. For that you would need `std::bind`.

Comment: @javaLover for your example code, the typical pattern is to use a non-member non-friend function as the hashing function (see for example `std::hash`)...

Comment: @101010 : As far as I know, each call of std::bind require a pointer of object.  I have looked into it, but don't know how to apply to this AMap.  (with 1 line of code requirement)   or you mean it is impossible?  If so, please write it in your answer.

Comment: @101010 : (reply edited answer) Sorry, my template signature is misleading, the map is mapping form G -> int, not G -> function.  (I have edited my question.)  The function signature is assumed to be same across every member of a single map, so I shouldn't assign function as value of map like that. (only 1 function should be used for 1 map)  With my low capability, I can't adapt your answer to the case of G->int as well.   May you provide another example about G->int, please?