# C++ Pass lambda to template parameter

Tags: c++11, templates, lambda

How to pass lambda as template parameter.
For example this code

```
template<void (*callback)()>
void function() {
    callback();
}

int main() {
    function<[]() -> void { std::cout << "Hello world\n"; }>();
}
```

fails with error "invalid template argument for 'function', expected compile-time constant expression".
What I'm doing wrong.

**Edit**
I want to implement something like this

```
template<typename T,
        T (*deserializer)(buffer *data),
        void (*serializer)(T item, buffer *data)>
class Type {
public:
    T item;

    Type(T item) : item(item) {
    }

    Type(buffer *data) {
        deserialize(data);
    }

    void serialize(buffer *data) {
        serializer(item, data);
    }

    void deserialize(buffer *data) {
        deserializer(data);
    }
};

typedef Type<int, [](buffer* data) -> int { return -1; }, [](int item, buffer* data) -> void {}> IntType

typedef Type<long, [](buffer* data) -> long { return -1; }, [](long item, buffer* data) -> void {}> LongType
```

Comment: I'm planning to use it with class templates, this is just test code.

Comment: I was about to close the question as a duplicate of [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810519/how-to-use-a-lambda-expression-as-a-template-parameter), but neither the question nor the answers there are stellar...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lambdas in C++14, including their conversion to function pointers, are not constexpr.

In C++17, [this is going to change](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf).  There are no stable compilers with that feature implemented that I'm aware of (if you find one, can you mention it in the comments below?).

At that point

```
constexpr auto tmp = []() -> void { std::cout << "Hello world\n"; };
function<+tmp>();
```

will definitely work.  I am uncertain if

```
function<+[]() -> void { std::cout << "Hello world\n"; }>()
```

would work; there are some rules about lambdas in unevaluated contexts and inside template argument lists that may be separate from the `constexpr` lambda problem and may apply here.

We can hack it in C++14.

Create a template class that stores a static copy of a lambda and exposes a static function with the same signature (`f_ptr`) that calls that static copy of a lambda.

Instantiate it once globally with your lambda.

Pass a pointer to the `f_ptr` to your template.

So:

```
template<class L> struct stateless; // todo
template<class L> stateless<L> make_stateless(L l){return std::move(l);}

auto foo = make_stateless( []() -> void { std::cout << "Hello world\n"; } );

function< &foo::f_ptr >();
```

this is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Related: this works in clang, but current gcc has a bug and incorrectly rejects the lamba because it has no linkage (neither global nor `static`).  [Can I use the result of a C++17 captureless lambda constexpr conversion operator as a function pointer template non-type argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47606810) has a link to the GCC bug report.

Comment: I am confused by the syntax `function<+tmp>()`. Naively, I wanted to write: `function<tmp>()`, but that doesn't work. Why is the `+` needed here?

Comment: @KaiPetzke `+` does promotion of certain types; like, `+true` is `int` with value `1` because `true` is promoted to `int` by unary `+`.  In the case of lambdas, it acts as a promote-to-function-pointer-with-matching-signature.  This is more true by accident than design -- any class with an implicit operator that converts to a single pointer type works likes this -- but it turns out to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The kind of template in the example does not take a type as a parameter, but rather a value. This value needs to be determinable at runtime, in order to instantiate the template, and the value of a lambda is not a compile time constant, so this method just wont do. The common way of sending functors to a function is:

```
template<typename Func>
void foo(Func&& f)
{
    f();
}
```

And since you want a class template (please put such information in the question, not the comments), here is an example using classes:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename Func>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(Func&& f) : f(f) {}
    void Run() { f(); }
private:
    Func f;
};

template<typename Func>
MyClass<Func> MakeMyClass(Func&& f)
{
    return { std::forward<Func>(f) };
}

int main()
{
    auto x = MakeMyClass( [](){} );
    x.Run();
}
```